# Laravel 5 file delete issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a file in public/images/demo.jpg but unable to delete by `File::delete(public/images/demo.jpg)` in windows. How to solve the issue.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: No error file does not delete

Comment: If there's a problem deleting the file, any error is silently ignored. If it's important that a file was deleted, check it's existence after deleting it with File::exists().

Comment: Check if file exists because I think that Laravel Fille::delete needs a relative path to public_path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with the correct path:

```
File::delete(public_path('images/demo.jpg'));
```

Answer (score 0):

your path is not a string !!!

The following should work ...

```
$file_path = public_path().'/images/demo.jpg';

if(File::exists($file_path)){
   File::delete($file_path);
}
```